# basic app with es6 modules not working chrome - ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, es6-modules

I am creating a basic app with es6 modules and react with a node server. The index.html serves the index.js file as a module, but the module does not get loaded and the console shows the error :
GET http://localhost:3000/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

https://codesandbox.io/embed/veriz-210fb

https://github.com/stanleyjohnson/veriz

To reproduce : clone repo, npm i, npm start, go to http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable [static files serving](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) by adding the following line to your `server.js` file:

```js
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

so your file should look like this:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html',{ root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(port);
```